# Can we mix audio and video like a video editor in html / js / php

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

So I have to mix separate audio and video files. Just like a video editor does. But I have to do in html, js or php. I found a question about mixing audio and video file in webpage. That is working fine for me in webpage. But when I try to download that video it only downloads video not audio as audio is a seperate file and works as it:-

```
<script>
var video_elem = document.getElementById("vid");
video_elem.addEventListener('play', videoPausePlayHandler, false);
video_elem.addEventListener('pause', videoPausePlayHandler, false);
function videoPausePlayHandler(e) {
    if (e.type == 'play') {
        document.getElementById("aud").play();
    } else if (e.type == 'pause') {
        document.getElementById("aud").pause();
    }
}
```

I know that this code isn't mixing those so if I press download in video it won't download audio. Any suggestion how I can mix it so if I press download button in video it video gets audio and store it in that video file not a separate file. Sorry for my bad English and thanks for your suggestion in advance.